# Prove that: $\frac{d}{dt} M_{g_1,g_2,...,g_n}=M_{g'_1,g_2,...,g_n}+M_{g_1,g'_2,...,g_n}+...+M_{g_1,g_2,...,g'_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, determinant

> If we take $n$ vectors $w_1,w_2,...,w_n \in \mathbb R^n$ then $\det(w_1,w_2,...,w_n)=M_{w_1,w_2,...,w_n}(t)$.
>  Let $g_1,g_2,...,g_n: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$.  Knowing what is $M_{w_1,w_2,...,w_n}(t)$ prove that: $$\frac{d}{dt} M_{g_1,g_2,...,g_n}=M_{g'_1,g_2,...,g_n}+M_{g_1,g'_2,...,g_n}+...+M_{g_1,g_2,...,g'_n}$$

Assume that: 
$$g_1(x)=w_1=(w_{11},w_{12},...,w_{1n})$$
$$g_2(x)=w_2=(w_{21},w_{22},...,w_{2n})$$
$$...$$
$$g_n(x)=w_n=(w_{n1},w_{n2},...,w_{nn})$$
Then we must prove that:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \det \begin{bmatrix} w_{11} & w_{21} & ... & w_{n1} \\ w_{12} & w_{22} & ... & w_{n2} \\ ... & ... & ... & ... \\ w_{1n} & w_{2n} & ... & w_{nn} \end{bmatrix}= \det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & w_{21} & ... & w_{n1} \\ 1 & w_{22} & ... & w_{n2} \\ ... & ... & ... & ... \\ 1 & w_{2n} & ... & w_{nn} \end{bmatrix}+ ...+\det \begin{bmatrix} w_{11} & w_{21} & ... & 1 \\ w_{12} & w_{22} & ... & 1 \\ ... & ... & ... & ... \\ w_{1n} & w_{2n} & ... & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
However I don't have any idea how to show this. I thought about integral because on the left of equality I have a derivative but I don't know if it can be helpful.
Can you give me some tips?

Comment: You can use the Leibniz rule.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven but in the Leibniz rule I must have specific intervals integrability: from $a$ to $b$

Comment: I meant the Leibniz rule for derivatives. Namely, $$ \frac{d}{dt} F(g_1(t), \dots, g_n(t)) =\sum_{j=1}^n (\partial_j F)(g_1(t), \dots, g_n(t))\cdot g_j'(t) $$ for $g_k$ being scalar valued. However, in this case, we can do everything by hand, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do the thing for $n=2$ and leave it to you to generalise. Note that $\det$ is multilinear. Hence, we get
$$  \frac{1}{h} \left( \det(v(t+h), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t))  \right) = \frac{1}{h} \left( \det (v(t+h), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t+h)) \right) + \frac{1}{h} \left( \det(  v(t), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t))   \right)
= \det\left( \frac{1}{h}(v(t+h)-v(t)), w(t+h)\right) + \det\left( v(t), \frac{1}{h} ( w(t+h)-w(t))\right) .$$
Now use the continuity of the determinant and conclude. The general case works with the same idea, is just more annoying to write down.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I still don't understand your idea, could you say something more?

Comment: Which part is unclear to you? Then I can elaborate on that. The basic idea is that I want to compute the derivative just using the definition. We are considering the function $F(t)= \det(v(t), w(t))$ and want to take the derivative of that. Hence, I need to compute $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} (F(t+h) -F(t)) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} (\det(v(t+h), w(t+h)) -\det(v(t), w(t)) $$ Now I use the multilinearity of the determinant to much the differential quotient inside. Pulling the limit inside (as det is cont.) and get the derivative of $v$, resp. $w$ inside, exactly as wanted.

Comment: I don't understand why $ \frac{1}{h} \left( \det(v(t+h), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t))  \right) = \frac{1}{h} \left( \det (v(t+h), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t+h)) \right) + \frac{1}{h} \left( \det(  v(t), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t))   \right)$ because you add an additional factor here and I don't know why the value does not change

Comment: Because those two factors exactly cancel each other. This is the standard trick in analysis, you write $0=a-a$. Looks stupid, but is pretty useful :)

Comment: Oh great that you used this example: $0=a-a$ because of course it is well known to me and thanks to it I was able to notice that a small error crept into your solution and that's why I didn't understand. You wrote: $t=t+\frac{1}{h} \left( \det(  v(t), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t))   \right)$ instead of $t=t+\frac{1}{h} \left( \det(  v(t), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t+h))   \right)$

Comment: It seems to me that what I wrote is correct. Let me include some more details: $$ \frac{1}{h} \left( \det(v(t+h), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t))  \right) = \frac{1}{h} \left( \det (v(t+h), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t+h))+  \det(  v(t), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t))   \right) =
 \frac{1}{h} \left( \det (v(t+h), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t+h)) \right) + \frac{1}{h} \left( \det(  v(t), w(t+h)) - \det(v(t), w(t))   \right)= \det\left( \frac{1}{h}(v(t+h)-v(t)), w(t+h)\right) + \det\left( v(t), \frac{1}{h} ( w(t+h)-w(t))\right) $$ Is it clearer now?

Comment: Would you like to check if my solution is now fully correct? First of all, I mean whether everything is well justified or should I add something else

Comment: I would suggest that you post an answer for the general case as a separate answer. Then everybody can give you feedback and you can also gain some reputation.